# Application.wait is not executing where it has been written

Tags: vba

I want to give 10 second delay between two statements of a macro.I am giving command to other software using excel vba

With wsActive

```
ExportPath = "C:\"
sTempFileNamevbs = ExportPath & Trim(.Name) & ".vbs"
iFileNumvbs = FreeFile
Open sTempFileNamevbs For Output As #iFileNumvbs
Print #iFileNumvbs, "Set Processes = GetObject(" & Chr(34) & "winmgmts:" & Chr(34) & ").InstancesOf(" & Chr(34) & "Win32_Process" & Chr(34) & ")"
Print #iFileNumvbs, "For Each Process In Processes"
Print #iFileNumvbs, "If StrComp(Process.Name, " & Chr(34) & "abcd.exe" & Chr(34) & ", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then"
Print #iFileNumvbs, "With CreateObject(" & Chr(34) & "WScript.Shell" & Chr(34) & ")"
Print #iFileNumvbs, ".AppActivate Process.ProcessId"
orty = w.Cells(j, 4).Value

**'that time delay is executing here before running of below statements**

If (Trim(orty) = "this") Then

Print #iFileNumvbs, ".SendKeys " & Chr(34) & "{Esc}" & Chr(34) & ""
Print #iFileNumvbs, ".SendKeys " & Chr(34) & "+{F3}" & Chr(34) & ""
Print #iFileNumvbs, ".SendKeys " & Chr(34) & "{Esc}" & Chr(34) & ""
Print #iFileNumvbs, ".SendKeys " & Chr(34) & "+{F3}" & Chr(34) & ""
End If

inst = w.Cells(j, 15).Value
nsenfo = w.Cells(j, 1).Value
limitsl = w.Cells(j, 5).Value
```

**Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))**
     **'this time delay is not executing here**

```
If (Trim(nsenfo) = "NSE") And (Trim(limitsl) = "SL") Then

Print #iFileNumvbs, ".SendKeys"; Spc(1); "" & Chr(34) & ""; "+{TAB 4}"; "" & Chr(34) & ""
Print #iFileNumvbs, ".SendKeys"; Spc(1); "" & Chr(34) & ""; w.Cells(j, 5).Value; "" & Chr(34) & ""
```

Comment: What's the point of the delay? It does not serve any purpose in this code.

Comment: On a more general note - are you dynamically creating VBScript code so you can execute that from your VBA macro? If yes, don't do that.

Comment: this code place orders in a stock market software. BY pressing shift+F3 it opens order window and fills all values taken from a sheet. but some time window takes 1 or 2 second in appearing after shift+F3 , but values filling starts immediately which results in error. So some delay is necessary after pressing shift+F3 to make sure that order window has opened .but this delay is executing before opening the order window.

Comment: Actually this code is not written by me I am not a programmer. I am just editing it.

Comment: Yeah, this cannot work. This VBA code generates *different* code (VBScript) and stores it in a file. Later (I presume) this VBScript file is executed. No amount of time spent waiting in your VBA macro will make the VBScript code slower.

Comment: What you really need to do here is throw out all the code that creates and executes a VBS file. All of that work can be and should be done from within VBA. But if you're scared of that, you could throw out the `Application.Wait` line and instead add `Print #iFileNumvbs, "WScript.Sleep(10000)"` to make the VBScript wait 10 seconds (`WScript.Sleep` takes milliseconds).

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not a pretty solution, but the original code doesn't win any beauty contests to begin with. :) I'm putting my comment up as an actual answer below, please remember to tick the "accepted" check mark so this thread is marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This VBA macro generates *different* code (VBScript) and stores it in a file. Later this VBScript file seems to executed separately. No amount of time spent waiting in your VBA macro will make the VBScript code slower.

What you really need to do here is throw out all the code that creates and executes a VBS file. All of that work can be and should be done from within VBA. Something like this - the code is basically exactly the same, but *less*, since it does not need the part that writes a file:

```vb
Dim Processes, Process As Variant
Dim Shell As Object

Set Processes = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

For Each Process In Processes
  If StrComp(Process.Name, "abcd.exe", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    Shell.AppActivate Process.ProcessId

    If Trim(w.Cells(j, 4).Value) = "this" Then
      Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")

      With Shell
        .SendKeys "{Esc}"
        .SendKeys "+{F3}"
        .SendKeys "{Esc}"
        .SendKeys "+{F3}"
      End If
    End If

    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

But if you're scared of making that kind of a change, you could throw out the `Application.Wait` line from your current code and instead add:

```vb
Print #iFileNumvbs, "WScript.Sleep(10000)"
```

to make add the innstruction to wait to the VBScript file. (WScript.Sleep takes milliseconds).

Comment: will this work with all versions of excel ? and with previous code I was given an EULA.bat file which has some registry editing having a term "ENABLEeUAC". what is the use of this file .

Comment: @user1447820 Yeah, both approaches will work in all versions of Excel. No idea about the .bat file.

Comment: facing a issue with this new code, even if programme abcd.exe not running this code send keys and that keys are typed on excel where I pressed button to call this macro.

Comment: You need to move the key presses into the `For` loop, see modified answer. (Anyway - you are not supposed to copy my code, but to adapt your code *in the same faith*)

Comment: one more query, I want to give 0.5 (half) second interval then how do it using  Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")

Comment: @user1447820 Not sure. That's actually a good separate question you could ask here - "How to wait tenths of seconds with Application.Wait?" (although I would argue that this might already have been asked before somewhere on the Internet.

Comment: hello, I have a new problem. the line Shell.AppActivate Process.ProcessId does not restore or activate abcd.exe if it minimized. I added a separate question for that here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764525/bring-a-window-programme-to-foreground-in-full-screen-and-minimize-others-includ?noredirect=1#comment111007370_62764525

please answer if you know.